# Getting java.lang.IllegalStateException When I unlcok screen

Tags: android

> When i launch app and lock the screen without clicking(playing audio) button and after when i unlock the screen and press the play button i am getting Exception.

```
public class DemoActivity extends Activity {
MediaPlayer mp;
Button btn;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
mp = MediaPlayer.create(DemoActivity.this,R.raw.mus);
btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
if (btn.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("play")) {
                mp.start();
                btn.setText("Pause");
            } else if (btn.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("pause")) {
                mp.pause();
                btn.setText("Play");
            }
}
    });
@Override
public void onPause() {
super.onPause();
    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
        mp.start();
    } else {
        mp.release();
    }
}
@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    try {
        if (mp.isPlaying() && mp!=null) {
            mp.start();
        } else {
            mp.release();
        }
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onRestart();
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mp.release();
}
```

}

> Here is my code please try to give me a solution.
>   Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to run it in debug mode and step over each command to check where the exception is being thrown?

Comment: Down vote. Explain what you attempted in order to solve this on your own. Did you debug? Did you inspect the stack trace to see where the problem originates from? You should also include the stack trace here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try call `mp.prepare()` before every `mp.start()`. You are getting the error because the mp is not yet ready for your use, and calling `start()` on that will cause IllegalStateException.